# How to compare two dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes each having two columns (for example, x and y). I need to compare the two dataframes and see whether any of the values in x or y or both x and y are similar in the two dataframes.

Comment: We'll need to know what the data frame contains: integers, numeric, factors, something else?  For example a really simple example data frame containing random numeric data can be made by `df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))` and two of these can be directly subtracted provided they have the same column names (but the order of your rows would be critical to a correct answer).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `all.equal` function. It does not sort the dataframes. It will simply check each cell in `data frame` against the same cell in another one. 
You can also use `identical()` function.

Answer (score 8):

Without an example I cannot be certain I understand what you want.  However, I think you want something like this.  If so, there are almost certainly better ways to do the same thing.

```
a <- matrix(c(1,2,
              3,4,
              5,6,
              7,8), nrow=4, byrow=T, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x","y")))

b <- matrix(c(1,2,
              9,4,
              9,6,
              7,9), nrow=4, byrow=T, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x","y")))

cc <- matrix(c(NA,NA,
              NA,NA,
              NA,NA,
              NA,NA), nrow=4, byrow=T, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x","y")))

for(i in 1:dim(a)[1]) {
for(j in 1:dim(a)[2]) {
if(a[i,j]==b[i,j]) cc[i,j]=a[i,j]
}
}

cc
```

EDIT: January 8, 2013

The following line will tell you which cells differ between the two matrices:

```
which(a != b, arr.ind=TRUE)

#      row col
# [1,]   2   1
# [2,]   3   1
# [3,]   4   2
```

If the two matrices, a and b, are identical then:

```
which(a != b)

# integer(0)

which(a != b, arr.ind=TRUE)

# row col
```

EDIT January 9, 2012

The following code demonstrates the effect that row names can have on `identical`, `all.equal` and `which` when one of the two data frames is created by subsetting a third data frame.  If row names differ between the two data frames being compared then neither `identical` nor `all.equal` will return `TRUE`.  However, `which` can still be used to compare the columns `x` and `y` between the two data frames.  If row names are set to `NULL` for each of the two data frames being compared then both `identical` and `all.equal` will return `TRUE`.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
     group  x  y 
       1   10 20
       1   10 20
       1   10 20
       1   10 20
       2    1  2
       2    3  4
       2    5  6
       2    7  8
", sep = "", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
     group  x  y 
       2    1  2
       2    3  4
       2    5  6
       2    7  8
", sep = "", header = TRUE)

# df3 is a subset of df1

df3 <- df1[df1$group==2,]

# rownames differ between df2 and df3 and
# therefore neither 'all.equal' nor 'identical' return TRUE
# even though the i,j cells of df2 and df3 are the same.
# Note that 'which' indicates no i,j cells differ between df2 and df3 

df2
df3

all.equal(df2, df3)
identical(df2, df3)
which(df2 != df3)

# set row names to NULL in both data sets and
# now both 'all.equal' and 'identical' return TRUE.
# Note that 'which' still indicates no i,j cells differ between df2 and df3

rownames(df2) <- NULL
rownames(df3) <- NULL

df2
df3

all.equal(df2, df3)
identical(df2, df3)
which(df2 != df3)
```